# Application Freezes between loop

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm using this code to find out nearest value from data table.

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows
        ToolStripProgressBar1.Value = ToolStripProgressBar1.Value + 1
        f = 0
        Using dbconnn As New OleDbConnection(connString)
            dbconnn.Open()
            While f <> 1
                Dim query1 As String = "Select [Alloted_Operator], [Avg_Eff] from ASkill_Matrix2 where [Operation_Type] = '" & row.Cells("Operation_Type").Value & "' and  [Avg_Eff] between " & Double.Parse(row.Cells("Req_perf").Value - a) & " and " & Double.Parse(row.Cells("Req_perf").Value + a) & " and [Alloted_Operator] not in (select All_Opr from A) "
                Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(query1, dbconnn)
                    Using reader1 = cmd.ExecuteReader

                        'If reader1.HasRows Then
                        If reader1.Read() Then
                            f = 1
                            'MessageBox.Show(i)
                            row.Cells("All_Opr").Value = reader1.GetValue(0)
                            row.Cells("Opr_Eff").Value = reader1.GetValue(1)
                            row.Cells("Exp_Prod").Value = Convert.ToDouble((60 * row.Cells("Opr_Eff").Value) / (row.Cells("Oprn_SAM").Value * 100))
                            row.Cells("Balance").Value = Convert.ToInt64(row.Cells("Exp_Prod").Value - Convert.ToInt64(Label1.Text))
                            row.Cells("Rem_Eff").Value = Convert.ToInt64(row.Cells("Opr_Eff").Value - row.Cells("Req_perf").Value)
                            Dim query29 As String = "insert into A ([Machine_Type], [Attatchment], [All_Opr]) Values ('" & CStr(row.Cells("Machine_Type").Value) & "', '" & CStr(row.Cells("Attatchment").Value) & "', '" & CStr(row.Cells("All_Opr").Value) & "')"
                            Using cmd1 As New OleDbCommand(query29, dbconnn)
                                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
                            End Using
                            If row.Cells("Rem_Eff").Value >= 20 Then
                                Dim query3 As String = "insert into Temp_Av_Opr ([Machine_Type], [Attatchment], [All_Opr],[Opr_Eff]) Values ('" & CStr(row.Cells("Machine_Type").Value) & "','" & CStr(row.Cells("Attatchment").Value) & "', '" & CStr(row.Cells("All_Opr").Value) & "', '" & CStr(row.Cells("Rem_Eff").Value) & "')"
                                Using cmd2 As New OleDbCommand(query3, dbconnn)
                                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                                End Using
                            End If
                        Else
                            a += 1
                        End If
                    End Using
                End Using
            End While
        End Using
    Next
```

this is freezing my windows application on the second run

Please help me in this or plz suggest me any other method to do the same.
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to do is to move anything (indeed *dbconn*) inside the first loop not using *row* up before the loop.

Second, if *f* never is assigned a value of 1, your second loop will run forever.